# WordPress: the_content filter on the front-page.php

Tags: php, wordpress

Any idea why `the_content filter` is not being applied when `front-page.php` file in use?

The code below in not getting executed when `front-page.php` in use; works with `index.php, page.php etc..`

```
function some_filter_name($content){

    echo "dummy text";
    return $content;

}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'some_filter_name' );
```

---

**UPDATE: Make sure you are actually using `the_content()` on the page. `the_content` filter is only applied on `the_content` element - i.e. you have to use this in your template**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be because in front-page.php you don't call the proper hook.
In wordpress the [`add_filter`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) function hooks a function to a specific filter action.
An example of filter action is [`the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content) but this filter action needs to exist in any page that you want to use the custom function for.

Examples that you should have in your `front-page.php` that the add_filter can use to hook your custom function:

```
<?php the_content('Read more...'); ?>
```

and

```
<?php 
global $more;    // Declare global $more (before the loop).
$more = 0;       // Set (inside the loop) to display content above the more tag.
the_content("More...");
?>
```

Make sure that in `front-page.php` you call `the_content` hook and that the post/page/cpt content is displayed then you function callback should fire too, if not then the issue is not from the hook and needs extra debug.